# PHP - Secure MP4 videos - Random URL- Token

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize in advance for my English.

I want to secure videos for playback. I make use of the token to do some hash url.
Example Direct Video Path is `something.com/videos/33ay6a/2a5y6a.mp4`

And the final url I want for example: `something.com/vid/hashed.mp4`

It should be secured for IP user, and have experience time url. Each time the url address is different.
Token example:

```
$token = "3a35xa!s.x@fq8d6";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far? Do you have any code that is almost working?

Comment: I have nothing yet, I tried something. But I do not know how to start, how to achieve the goal. That is why I ask. I know I have to generate and then translate. But how am I just confused.

Comment: A) Generate random string. B) Try saving that in your video's record in a column.

Comment: If you're using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that has a routing layer, this is trivial to add. The `/videos/$video_id` path can have the `$video_id` part broken out for you. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a good example of one that does this, and this is [described in the Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing). If you're not using a framework you have a lot of work to do to capture these arbitrary URLs and route them through to the correct location.

Comment: You could also hash the file path and just dump it in an Amazon S3 bucket and be done with it.

Comment: @tadman sorry but Amazon S3 no i have dedicated server for big videos... 
But Lavarer sound good. But how on this? Have sometnig tutorial?

Comment: Read the documentation at the Laravel site, which I linked. There's an introduction, plus all sorts of training available in other places. It's a popular system.

Comment: Ok thanks you. Otherwise, if I finally wanted to solve via pure php how should I proceed?